# Part of sentence alignement

Tags: text, parallel-processing, nlp, translation

I work on parallel texts in two languages.
Some tools exist to align sentences (ex: Hunalign).
But sentences are often too long for my use case. So I would like to align part of sentences.

Here is an example:

**Input**:

| French | English |
| --- | --- |
| Bonjour ! L'année dernière, je suis allé à Paris qui est la capitale de la France. | Hello! Last year, I went to Paris which is the capital of France. |

**Existing result** : Sentence level alignement:

| French | English |
| --- | --- |
| Bonjour ! | Hello! |
| L'année dernière, je suis allé à Paris qui est la capitale de la France. | Last year, I went to Paris which is the capital of France. |

**Expected result**: Part of sentence alignment:

| French | English |
| --- | --- |
| Bonjour ! | Hello! |
| L'année dernière, | Last year, |
| je suis allé à Paris | I went to Paris |
| qui est la capitale de la France. | which is the capital of France. |

Google Translate offers a hover function, which seems to do part of the job internally.
[image: Example with Google Translate]

Any idea about how to get this result from Google Translate API?
Any idea about how to do it with any other tool? I'm trying to cut sentences in chunks and evaluate similarity with Facebook LASER and Google Universal Sentence Encoder, without much success so far.

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution which is language agnostic, much like LASER is. Or which supports ~40 most common languages.

Thanks in advance for your kind advice

Comment: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=I%20went%20to%20Paris%20which%20is%20the%20capital%20of%20France&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0 and https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=je%20suis%20all%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20Paris%20qui%20est%20la%20capitale%20de%20la%20France&model=fr_core_news_sm&cpu=0&cph=0

Comment: Thanks @DhruvPathak. I saw this one and it looks nice indeed, except for the limitation of ~13 languages. I'm looking ideally for an idea which would be kinda language agnostic, like LASER by Facebook. I see that this was not explicit in the post description, I'll update it ASAP.